# Detecting MQ operations on client connection

Tags: ibm-mq

Imagine an application(A1) running on a server(S1) makes a  client connection to a Queue Manager(QM1) running on a different server(S2). Is it possible to extend the functionality of Queue Manager so that when the application makes a MQGET or MQPUT call on a queue on the Queue Manager, a message can be logged to a log file or some custom action can be performed?

Thanks,

Yash

Answer (score 3):

An API Exit can be used to log the API calls made by an application. This API exit can run on either S1 or S2 from your question.

The sample API Exit supplied with MQ (`amqsaxe`) would be a good starting point as that's all it does.

Remember that this will have a detrimental effect on the performance of your application.

**Further Reading**

- [The API exit sample program](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q024010_.htm)